# How can I safely retrieve this property of this object?

Tags: php, laravel, object, properties

I have a Stripe subscription object that looks like this...

```
subscription: {
    items: {
        data: [
            plan: {
                id: 'my_plan_id'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What's the best way to safely retrieve the plan id? Currently I am doing the following.

```
'plan_id' => $subscription->items->data[0]->plan->id,
```

But, it looks like that will fail if `items`, `data[0]`, or `plan`, is not set. I could do nest if statements like, `if (isset($subscription->items) && isset(data[0]) ...`, but I am not sure that is the best way.

Is there a PHP method or Laravel method that I can use to extract that property safely that would be cleaner than that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you're using PHP 7+, you can use the null coalesce operator:

```
'plan_id' => $subscription->items->data[0]->plan->id ?? $default,
```

This will evaluate the value if it's available, otherwise it will use the default, without generating any warnings or errors.

Example:

```
$foo = new stdClass();
var_dump($foo->bar->baz->data[0]->plan->id ?? null);
```

Output:

```
NULL
```

Comment: But if `items` is null, wouldn't the entire thing break with an error, `Error: trying to get property of non-object`?

Comment: Nope. It won't even break if `$subscription` is a non-object.

Comment: Cool, I am using PHP 7, so it looks like this is the best answer. Thanks!

Comment: This only works if you're accessing properties of a class/array. When using the same semantics but with methods PHP will throw. (Just a heads up for OO devs)

Answer (score 4):

You can use an [`isset`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function over the entire selector:

```
isset($subscription->items->data[0]->plan->id) ? $subscription->items->data[0]->plan->id : null;
```

Comment: This appears to be the same as @Alex's answer, but without using the null coalesce operator. I prefer his, as it is cleaner IMO. But, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**in PHP version 8**

you should use Nullsafe operator as follow:

> ```
> 'plan_id' => $subscription?->items?->data[0]?->plan->id,
> ```

Comment: Yeah.. sadly no this on php 7.  but ?? helps a little bit

Answer (score 0):

A rather cumbersome but generic method to access nested structures by a list of keys; can be made into a reusable function easily:

```
$id = array_reduce(['items', 'data', 0, 'plan', 'id'], function ($o, $k) {
    if (!$o) {
        return null;
    } else if (is_array($o) && isset($o[$k])) {
        return $o[$k];
    } else if (isset($o->$k)) {
        return $o->$k;
    }
}, $subscription);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take help of `ternary condition` to check if the value is set or not. If set then put that value otherwise put default as

```
$id=isset($subscription->items->data[0]->plan->id) ? $subscription->items->data[0]->plan->id : $your_dafault_value;
```

If the value is set then the `$id` looks like

```
$id='my_plan_id';//In most cases we should consider null as a default value
```

If the value is not set then the `$id` looks liks

```
 $id='your_dafault_value';
```